# The essential spectrum of Hilbert -Schmidt operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am having a hard time getting my head around the Hilbert -Schmidt operators.

Now I have a question about them: why is the essential spectrum of Hilbert -Schmidt operators is empty? The definition of the notation is as follows:

> If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $T\in\mathcal{L}(H)$ then $T$ is Hilbert-Schmidt if there is some orthonormal basis of $H$ such that:
> $$\sum_n \lVert T(e_n)\rVert_{H}^2<\infty$$
> And the essential spectrum consists of the continum spectrum and eigenvalues with infinite multiplicity.

I have trouble figuring out the reason why the Hilbert -Schmidt operators have no essential spectrums. Why do they have only discrete spectrums? Thanks very much!

Comment: You may find the fact that Hilbert-Schmidt operators are compact quite useful.

Comment: Oh! It comes to my mind. I have understood the reason,thank you.

Comment: Eigenvalues may have finite multiplicity only.

Comment: But in the theory of compact operator theory, 0 may be the accumulation point of the spectral set $\sigma(T)$ and thus be a continuous spectrum of $T$.   Is this an essential spectrum? I am a little confused.@uniquesolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Hilbert-Schmidt operator is compact. This means that any nonzero eigenvalue necessarily has a finite-dimensional eigenspace; and this immediately implies that the essential spectrum of a compact operator is $\{0\}$. This is simply the fact that $\sigma_{\rm ess}(T)=\sigma(\pi(T))$, where $\pi$ is the quotient map onto the Calkin algebra.